# Persian Strings in PHP with JSON result

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to write a php json webservice that have persian string in mysql db.
this is my table:
[image]

this is my code:
[image]

and result is:
[image]

if you see result you will see persian strings show as numbers and back slashes. why? i try any code to debug it but can not do it.
please help why persian strings not appear correctly.

Comment: It's basically no problem that the string is encoded this way in its plain form. JSON encodes all unusual utf characters into this hexadecimal representation. If you parse the JSON as a Javascript code or with any JSON parser, the string should be displayed correctly, try alert(theEncodedString) and you'll see if the encoding is actually corrupt or not.

Comment: What version of PHP use?

Comment: Stackoverflow supports text. Please use text to represent your code instead of low resolution screenshots.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why are my “special” Unicode characters encoded weird using json_encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476)

Comment: hi friends i got it in Maks3w's answer. thanks for all your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the unescape option in json_encode

> JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE (integer) Encode multibyte Unicode characters
>   literally (default is to escape as \uXXXX). Available since PHP 5.4.0.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

```
json_encode(array('Cinema' => $cinemas), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Answer (score 1):

> if you see result you will see persian strings show as numbers and back slashes. why?

Because PHP's `json_encode`, by default, outputs ASCII JSON, so non-ASCII characters are represented by escape sequences.

> why persian strings not appear correctly

There is nothing incorrect about using escape sequences for those characters.

You can use [the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) if you want to use unicode literals instead of escape sequences.

```
json_encode(array('Cinema' => $cinemas), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

Comment: @Maks3w — From the *question* (except, obviously, I had to transcribe it because the question is a picture for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

That is normal. JSON does support UTF-8 strings, however for maximum compatibility PHP encodes all non-ASCII characters as unicode escape sequences, `\u1324` with `1234` being the character's unicode position in hexadecimal.

The receiving code, for instance JavaScript, will decode these sequences when the string is run through `JSON.parse`.

Ultimately, it does't really matter how it works so long as it works, and in this case your code works ;)