# JSON communication corrupting special chars

Tags: javascript, php, json, character-encoding

While retrieving some data from an online db, I can't figure our why some characters get "misinterpreted".

I send the data from the server through a PHP app, like so:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// tried also header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
// tried also header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($object);
```

If I test the message, the JSON encoded string correctly contains the following string `\u00ec`, which represents the letter `ì`.

However, in the client, when I check the unparsed string, I see the following string instead: `\u00c3\u00ac`, which represent, respectively: `Ã` and `¬` (this happens with all special characters like èéàòùü etc.).

As a consequence, when i call JSON.parse() on the response, I see the wrong characters.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content you are encoding in json??

Comment: It is a quite complex array, but essentially everything is parsed in JSON correctly, that's why I included only the characters that are giving me troubles. For example, the string that I am looking at now to test the problem has the word `lunedì` (monday) in it, and that `ì` is giving me headaches...

Comment: before encoding in json, print the `$object` variable and check.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju the word `lunedì` appears as `lunedÃ¬`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PHP 5.4< you can pass `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` as the second parameter of the `json_encode` function.

Comment: Nope, still on 5.3. I'm planning to upgrade, but thats sort of a long time thing, while right now I need to solve this quite in the short time

Comment: Then take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932572/how-to-save-a-json-as-unescaped-utf-8-in-php-5-3

Comment: Thank's! I'm still testing it to figure out what's going on underhood, but as of now the problem seems to be fixed, which is great! :-). In case it might help anyone, I'm using the following header: `header('Content-Type: application/javascript; charset=utf-8');`