# Converting Hebrew characters to UTF-8 using PHP

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, ascii, hebrew

i have a MySQL field value with a json object containing Hebrew characters  like this:

```
[{"name":"אספנות ואומנות","value":1,"target":null},{"name":"אופניים","value":2,"target":null}]
```

(the one in the name field)

This field output is giving me some trouble with a certain web interface.
so, looking around in the database i found another field containing json object and its output works fine.

```
[{"name":"\u05d0\u05e1\u05e4\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea \u05d5\u05d0\u05d5\u05de\u05e0\u05d5\u05ea","value":1,"target":null},{"name":"\u05d0\u05d5\u05e4\u05e0\u05d9\u05d9\u05dd","value":2,"target":null}]
```

So i would like to convert the first field to this encoding to see if its solves the output issue.

what is this encoding ? is it UTF-8 ? how can i convert it using PHP ?

i tried to isolate the value and convert it to UTF-8 using

```
echo iconv("Windows-1255","UTF-8",'אספנות ואומנות');
```

but its just returning an empty value.

Any help would be great

Comment: no need to use iconv, thats unicode, just decode as is

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476

Comment: thanks @Ghost - but what does that mean ? what command should i use ? i could only find this function html_entity_decode(), there is no decode()

Comment: @buzibuzi check out deceze's link, should shed light to your confusion

Answer (score 1):

So, in PHP

```
json_encode('אספנות ואומנות');
```

did the trick