# echo currency symbol get wrong output

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with print currency symbol in php when i print currency symbol using echo function i got wrong output

i try this code 
i have array like

```
'Turkey New Lira - TRY' => 'も'
$key = $row['Currency']; $value = $array_currency[$key]; echo $value;
```

i have this code for print

```
$key = $row['Currency']; $value = $array_currency[$key]; echo $value;
```

i get output like

> ã‚‚

alse have problem with echo json_encode get output like

```
\u3082
```

give me right solution for this

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct `meta` headers in your page - with utf-8 that symbol displays correctly ... `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

Comment: buddy i have problem with json_encode echo

Comment: Turkish Lira are written using the Japanese "mo"...!?

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: [Reference: Why are my “special” Unicode characters encoded weird using json_encode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476)

Answer (score 0):

Add the meta tag to your html

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

For json_encode

```
$string="も";
echo $string."<br/>";
echo "Encoding: " . mb_detect_encoding($string) . "<br/>";
$encoded = json_encode($string);
echo "Encoded val: $encoded <br/>";    
$encoded2 = json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo "Encoded val(with param): $encoded2 <br/>";
$decoded = json_decode($encoded);
echo "Decoded val: $decoded <br/>";
```

ouput

```
も
Encoding: UTF-8
Encoded val: "\u3082" 
Encoded val(with param): "も" 
Decoded val: も
```

Comment: you have any solution for json_encode its work fine i only echo function

Comment: On json_decode you will get the exact value back

Comment: You can use json_encode($string, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); in higher version