# UTF-8 php-mysqli not working

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli, utf-8

I'm using ajax to get my results from my query. The ajax gives the response (sql query executes successfully) but some characters (croatian language) are broken, hence utf-8 doesn't function correctly.

In my php script, I've tried the following:

```
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

OR

```
$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

I've also added the following line in the header:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

as well as the content type in my client-ajax code:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

Still my characters break, I'm not getting utf-8 valid response.
In phpMyAdmin I've got the **utf8_general_ci** collation which I believe is ok.

Comment: Have you checked if they are also "broken" in the database?

Comment: They are not. The text is 100% percent normal (croatian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The second argument (JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) inside the json_encode() function was the problem.

```
echo json_encode($myArray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

So along with JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE you have to add the following line of code which is **ENOUGH**.

```
$con->set_charset('utf8');
```

If you switched  `$con->set_charset('utf8');` to `$con->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` then it **wouldn't work** (you'd get a server 500 error).

The  `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` **is not required**.

Before you fix your php code you have to make sure that when you run your query against the database in phyMyAdmin or smillar, the collation needs to be **utf8** in my case **utf8_general_ci**.

Of-course, don't forget the

> dataType: "json"

in jquery-ajax.

Comment: It would have helped if you'd have defined what "broken" means exactly... http://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476

Comment: I missed to write the json_encode function, therefore I assume I didn't get the right response...

Comment: You ultimately missed to describe your problem. You described what you did, you did at no point say what exactly was "wrong". Turns out, nothing was "wrong" at all...