# PHP - str_replace dont work

Tags: php, utf-8, str-replace

*(Sorry if my english is bad, but is not my language)*

In my PHP file I receive an object called `$ orderdetalle` that **is generated in a part of the server where I do not have access and I don't know the encode of the server** ...`$ orderdetalle` is an array that contains, in `string` fields, different values ​​and between they the lastname. But if the lastname is for example, `Hernández` the variable keeps`Hern\u00e1ndez`.

So that the lastname can later send it in a `json`, I am trying to do what I read in another similar question with `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()`:

```
$lastname_consumer = $ordendetalle['customer_lastname'];//I receive the lastname Hern\u00e1ndez
$str_lastname = str_replace('\u','u',$lastname_consumer);
$lastname = preg_replace('/u([\da-fA-F]{4})/', '&#x\1;', $str_lastname);

$customer = array ( 'customer' => array ( 'id' => $ordendetalle['customerId'], 
                                          'lastname' => $lastname, 
                                          'firstname' => $ordendetalle['firstname'],
                                          'email' => $ordendetalle['email']
                                        )
                  );

$customer_order = print_r(json_encode($customer), true); //Print in a log
```

My problem is that `$str_lastname` gets `Hern\u00e1ndez` instead of `Hernu00e1ndez` when doing the `str_replace()`, and its worthless to subsequently do the `preg_replace()` and gets `Hernández`.

On the other hand, I have tried the code in http://phptester.net/ and it works perfectly for me but I understand that it is a matter of `\u00e1` being a character **UTF-8**. So I do not know very well how to advance at this point.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** 
Add `var_dump($ordendetalle)`:

```
["customer_id"]=> string(3) "979"
["customer_email"]=> string(23) "email@test.es"
["customer_firstname"]=> string(7) "UserTest"
["customer_lastname"]=> string(10) "Hernández"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha#comment23799170_7981441 suggests using (abusing?) `json_decode` for this.

Comment: Are you sure you're not simply dealing with JSON here…?

Comment: @TobiasK `"lastname": "Hern\u00e1ndez"` print in the log when `print_r(json_decode('{"lastname": "'.$lastname_consumer.'"}'));`

Comment: Please give us a clear sample of your data with `var_dump($ordendetalle)`.

Comment: The `json_decode` approach works for me: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b839dd137d3261f254c3352bdf86479ebede2efc

Comment: In http://phptester.net/ also works... but in real...

Comment: @deceze var_dump added

Comment: There's no `\u...` in that `var_dump`…?! Guessing from the `string(10)` the string is nicely encoded in UTF-8…!?

Comment: I'm guessing you might want to read [Reference: Why are my “special” Unicode characters encoded weird using json_encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476)

Comment: Ohh works! If you write an answer I accept it right now :)  Thanks @deceze

Answer (score 1):

the issue come from the fact that each value in your $ordendetalle array is already encoded with json_encode 
    so you can do:

```
$ordendetalle=array_map('json_decode',$ordendetalle);
$customer = array ( 'customer' => array ( 'id' => $ordendetalle['customerId'], 
                                          'lastname' => $lastname, 
                                          'firstname' => $ordendetalle['firstname'],
                                          'email' => $ordendetalle['email']
                                        )
                  );

$customer_order = print_r(json_encode($customer), true); //Print in a log
```

Comment: After add $ordendetalle=array_map('json_decode',$ordendetalle); string values became null. "lastname": null,
  "firstname": null,
  "email": null