# È char saves as ? in file php

Tags: php, encoding

I'm trying to save string to a file but we're getting a ? instead of the char.
What would be the best way of being able to save chars like `"È"` to a file as a readable char.
And also being able `to html_decode($str)` the string in php?

--UPDATE -----

adding "mysql:charset=utf8mb4;" to the PDO database connection fixed the problem.

-- STILL ENCOUNTERING PROBLEMS --

even though when I echo the string to the terminal now I can see it properly in the terminal. But once I save it to the file I get this:

```
CAF\u00c9
```

-- FILE SAVE EXAMPLE --

```
$jsonStr = '';

... process to query db and get string with utf-8 connection
and loop over all results and append a json_encoded string to each new line

loop start

    $jsonStr .= json_encode($array) . "\n";

loop end

file_put_contents($path, $jsonStr);
```

-- ANSWER --

json_encode needs the "JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE" flag as a second param

Comment: How are you "saving it to the file" exactly…?

Comment: Please see sample scenario above

Comment: Well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22745662/476