# How to json encode result from object response?

Tags: php, json

I would like to send JSON back from a PHP API processor script. For the error messaging, Im accessing it like this:

```
try {
    $tax = $client->taxForOrder([
    "field"=>($value),
    "field"=>($value),
    //etc
);
$data = $tax;
//json encoding works here
echo json_encode($data);
}
catch (TaxJar\Exception $e) {
    // 406 Not Acceptable – transaction_id is missing
    echo $e->getMessage();
    // 406
    echo $e->getStatusCode();
}
```

With the above, it returns plain text "400 Bad Request – to_zip 66762 is not used within to_state NJ400" as expected. But I would like JSON, as the jQuery $.ajax success function is looking for a dataType of "JSON".
When I try:

```
   $msg = $e->getMessage();
   echo json_encode($msg);
```

It doesn't return anything. How do I correctly get something like {"error","msg":"400 Bad Request..."}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first build a PHP array.

```php
$response = ['status' => 'error', 'msg' => $e->getMessage()];
echo json_encode($response );
```

Becarful, exception managment when you send the error to the client has to safely be done. I mean that depending on how you treat exception, you might place debug informations in the exception message. This might give informations to a potantial hacker.

Maybe create a new exception class, like a ClientErrorException class. And send the exception message to the client only if the exception of this class. If not, just send a generic message "an internal server error occured"

Comment: Thank you - I wasn't sure how to build the array correctly and this answered it. How would I convert "\u2013" to "–" in the response? How would you create another new exception class in this situation where Im accessing classes from their API?

Comment: I would create a ClientErrorException class. The code of the exception would be 400 by default. This code would be use to send the HTTP status code. Depending on the error type, you can specify a more precise code. All exception would be catched at the higher level of my application where I will treat all exceptions if they are not catched before. If an external class or API throw on exception, i would probably catch and treat it and then depending on the information that the exception might give me, i would throw a ClientErrorException or let the original one spread.

Comment: For the character encoding problem (\u2013), you can have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745662/reference-why-are-my-special-unicode-characters-encoded-weird-using-json-enco