# Trouble decoding string from JSON in PHP \u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8, instagram

TLDR: Trying to convert the string `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac` to `日本` in php.
(Trying to get `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac` to echo out `日本`)

Hi folks,

I have a json file from Instagram (downloaded my data) and many of my posts contain Japanese text which is stored encoded in UTF-8 (and please correct me if I'm wrong, especially as `mb_detect_encoding("\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac")` returns `"ASCII"`).

For example `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac` becomes `日本`.

The conversions can be seen working fine on this encoder/decoder website:
https://mothereff.in/utf-8

(Note that if you put `日本` into the above site it returns `\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC`, so adding `\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC \u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac` to the encoded field will produce `日本 日本` in the decoded field)

I'm trying to convert it back to regular Japanese text but am having issues.

I've been googling and looking over Stackoverflow for just over a day and have been trying many different methods, but I just can't get it to convert. I'm clearly missing something. In most cases it does not change at all.

For the scope of this question, I'm simply trying to convert `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac` into `日本`.
I am not trying to convert the json file (though am open to any suggestions that would need me to).

(For the record I am using the variable `$str` for `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac`)

The following attempts resulted in no visible change, `\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac`

```
echo call_user_func_array('mb_convert_encoding', array(&$str,'HTML-ENTITIES','UTF-8'));
echo iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8', $str);
echo iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $str);
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $str);
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($str));
echo iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $str);
echo iconv('ISO-8859-9', 'UTF-8', $str);
echo iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $str);
echo htmlentities($str);
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'utf-8', 'iso-8859-1');
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "EUC-JP", "auto");
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "utf-8", "windows-1251");
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "windows-1251", "utf-8");
echo mb_convert_encoding($str,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
echo mb_convert_encoding($str,"UTF-8","auto");
echo mb_convert_encoding($str,"UTF-8");
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', array('EUC-JP', 'SHIFT-JIS', 'AUTO'));
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($str, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "ISO-8859-1", mb_detect_encoding($str, "UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15", true));
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
echo utf8_decode($str);
echo utf8_encode($str);
```

The following attempt resulted in the slash being duplicated with double quotation marks added, `"\\u00e6\\u0097\\u00a5\\u00e6\\u009c\\u00ac"`

```
echo json_encode($str,JSON_HEX_TAG);
echo json_encode($str,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE |JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo json_encode($str,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE|JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

The following attempt resulted in nothing being returned,

```
echo json_decode($str, JSON_HEX_TAG);
echo json_decode($str, false);
echo json_decode($str, false, 512, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

The following attempted resulted in the slashes changing to an unknown character, `�_u00e6�_u0097�_u00a5�_u00e6�_u009c�_u00ac`

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS");
```

From the PHP documentation I tried this to see if any of the combinations would work, but none did.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php#97902

```
foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
    echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', $chr)." : ".$chr."<br>";   
}
echo "<br>--- REVERSE TRY ---<br><br>";
foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
    echo mb_convert_encoding($str, $chr, 'UTF-8')." : ".$chr."<br>";   
}
```

I tried using the Unicode Codepoint Escape Syntax, which gave `æ—¥æœ¬`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.unicode-codepoint-escape-syntax

```
echo "\u{00e6}\u{0097}\u{00a5}\u{00e6}\u{009c}\u{00ac}";
```

As mentioned in the brackets earlier, `\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC` does convert to `日本` when echoed.

```
echo "\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC";
```

Noticing above that the two different codes had the same endings, I tried using `str_replace` so that they would match, but this time `\xE6\x97\xA5\xE6\x9C\xAC` was echoed.

```
echo str_replace("\U00","\x",strtoupper($str));
```

I have also tried all of the above with and without the following:

```
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"');
```

Here is a segment of the original JSON file (original file is 13k lines, so here is a single element).

```
{
    "media": [
      {
        "uri": "media/posts/202104/175127092_241529264421003_4026764649651789139_n_18106766305234668.jpg",
        "creation_timestamp": 1619277565,
        "title": "Time to head back to Tokyo.\nFukuoka Airport, Japan.\n18 October 2020\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n#japan #\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac #toyphotography #toy #\u00e3\u0081\u008a\u00e3\u0082\u0082\u00e3\u0081\u00a1\u00e3\u0082\u0083 #\u00e3\u0083\u00ad\u00e3\u0083\u009b\u00e3\u0082\u0099\u00e3\u0083\u0083\u00e3\u0083\u0088  #GodJesusRobot #robot #toyholiday  #holiday #vacation #\u00e6\u0097\u0085\u00e8\u00a1\u008c #photography  #\u00e5\u0086\u0099\u00e7\u009c\u009f #japan_of_insta #japantravel #\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac\u00e6\u0097\u0085\u00e8\u00a1\u008c #travel #kitakyushu #\u00e5\u008c\u0097\u00e4\u00b9\u009d\u00e5\u00b7\u009e #airport #\u00e7\u00a9\u00ba\u00e6\u00b8\u00af #fukuokaairport #\u00e7\u00a6\u008f\u00e5\u00b2\u00a1\u00e7\u00a9\u00ba\u00e6\u00b8\u00af #plane #airplane #aeroplane #\u00e9\u00a3\u009b\u00e8\u00a1\u008c\u00e6\u00a9\u009f #windowseat #window"
      }
    ]
  }
```

***UPDATE***

Based on the comments by @jerry and @yourcommonsense, `hexbin` can work so the string will have to be converted by dropping the `\u00`. `hex2bin(str_replace('\u00', '', $str));` will definitely work for the string mentioned in the TLDR and upper part of the question, but to tackle the full title string in the json I've come up with a very ugly and messy method.

```
$str = "Time to head back to Tokyo.\nFukuoka Airport, Japan.\n18 October 2020\n.\n.\n.\n.\n.\n#japan #\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac #toyphotography #toy #\u00e3\u0081\u008a\u00e3\u0082\u0082\u00e3\u0081\u00a1\u00e3\u0082\u0083 #\u00e3\u0083\u00ad\u00e3\u0083\u009b\u00e3\u0082\u0099\u00e3\u0083\u0083\u00e3\u0083\u0088  #GodJesusRobot #robot #toyholiday  #holiday #vacation #\u00e6\u0097\u0085\u00e8\u00a1\u008c #photography  #\u00e5\u0086\u0099\u00e7\u009c\u009f #japan_of_insta #japantravel #\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac\u00e6\u0097\u0085\u00e8\u00a1\u008c #travel #kitakyushu #\u00e5\u008c\u0097\u00e4\u00b9\u009d\u00e5\u00b7\u009e #airport #\u00e7\u00a9\u00ba\u00e6\u00b8\u00af #fukuokaairport #\u00e7\u00a6\u008f\u00e5\u00b2\u00a1\u00e7\u00a9\u00ba\u00e6\u00b8\u00af #plane #airplane #aeroplane #\u00e9\u00a3\u009b\u00e8\u00a1\u008c\u00e6\u00a9\u009f #windowseat #window";
$pattern = '/(\\\\u00..)+/i';

function getHex2Bin($matches) {
    return hex2bin(str_replace("\U00","",strtoupper($matches[0])));
}

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'getHex2Bin', $str);
echo $result;
```

This *does* work, giving me my desired result:
`Time to head back to Tokyo. Fukuoka Airport, Japan. 18 October 2020 . . . . . #japan #日本 #toyphotography #toy #おもちゃ #ロボット #GodJesusRobot #robot #toyholiday #holiday #vacation #旅行 #photography #写真 #japan_of_insta #japantravel #日本旅行 #travel #kitakyushu #北九州 #airport #空港 #fukuokaairport #福岡空港 #plane #airplane #aeroplane #飛行機 #windowseat #window` but I can't help feel that there is a much neater solution.

***Update 2***

Here is a PHP Sandbox [showing the results](https://onlinephp.io?s=vVdtj6M2EP6-Uv6DS1YFVMjbNbukd-0pzbGbrK6bKCFVq6ZChjgLmyxGxuwlOu1_r23MQl72Sj60UWTM-JlnxjPDYD58jIO4dtFsAjuiiIAdTgnw8RKBABFkABQ94t13tYvLhBLwM1AWaauFrvjYu-Yj7JYkvpD4yvvaRe0C-QEGPtxs3DRBxF2lke9CQuBOU58818fRMyLURREzFkYPqgGyxe-5JUMdOr99Nu17Z-SM7JlqqHPnxrRUXW9MhhPXHn9-Lw2EnEhT-7PBaMQ4JM4AnOUNsCIwigGUwaTd6XaUb6JfGdXRbGxaVrdntr_NX2iISbM5ur0fT20mSOnKynaMNEHwFsOeqSp7KjR6FTVYDpaIIr9IgXDJAMUCJktENN0AlKSIXV4Dd5I2oE8bFNGQhijRTiJOpF3aVFlkspCFCc53foa-Ys8H5t2E5xSmFCvnqArTXPNLGC3xl8RkNdE-i2FP8ZWxOsNhsef5q86QZ-bc3Uu9czKVl5Z8lLPAc59nw9GNY96NxAb6c2d84mmtwFuu_XOSkNfmm3WdIQxQ8JfnXUWW-Tk2C_X_1_DJ_nCkL7rNEhXd5iSg3I4OAY8JjsoMBribje_dof2H6_RvK8BXcJOgqjgDdNsdaWJ-b88G_Yn9ic1Gg_En-5y0zFgR7tX0ChME_YD3vE2YFAqJpgOYgEs_IPrX2gVgv6PAVChZoa83FPATUBr8pqF88MgvSsmDF-m1WDBNE0zt3-3pzAbO9E_A7rn4UOe_8ZqrFTVT0etF-pW_5F_EtXedXWH3ZV_uS7n_ohxmS1ls7avFlp0Ztv2unA_YfHCEZE66BMUb6CNNWcxbLdbVFlvFYHKK0zhmb6SjV2dxPHHCJwQoexkhuAQe9Nf8xsHrHW4sopt0neI1BP2QxJhQVmowhhFbaFtg7FPssfNPp9VpLbis_K8_ciCoVzn8gDrFuzjAFD8QGAc7cS9V3_HRaosRliSdYixjYPsI826PSYxweSjpeYd6vd4hJhv3JBYA9Vu8vENJmkyxhymok-zCdhDgTbiEOwbJZ_Vn6EMa4hNxsbK4WMUmLBaXclCkjsBZVyUXr4tY9lYgC7yLV24YJRTKe0rgM9pUS0c113LGdUjhepcmQbrnoF_oox_56Alne8sC42WOI1CHWXVJgswxAfdg4YyXOcB2uMqK8pSWQFqrkpFOqSz-lZk9Q5H0R84QwXIq8EIXlktmLywFZ2aF50MedRCk-Zwf9i9jSNnHQ8SeQLWpLdiPwRsN_YdmqIrHkx_-Rak8IDpE286vYaRdPkHqByjRgWxiBNGUcQRs3WPrpxrBfhuQBH-1_tZ1PWtXzBfC6ndDmSsxQQ85g8s_RHg_0HJfWQ8snMmPynkTkiSvLeYf&v=8.1.8) of all attempts mentioned above, including the messy working one.

Comment: What is "regular Japanese text"? There is no such encoding. The sequence looks like Unicode.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I have added an element from the JSON file. This is what is downloaded from Instagram.

Comment: partial answer: `echo hex2bin('E697A5E69CAC');`

Comment: well, an ugly solution is `hex2bin(str_replace('\u00', '', $str));`. But there must be a correct one for sure.

Comment: How did you obtain this string?  It is UTF-8 byte values, but translated to Latin-1 code points.

Comment: Everything I read says that `json_decode` SHOULD treat that string as unicode, and decode it to create the hex data. Empirically, it does not. And I have to wonder why, if they're using unicode, they have to ALSO binhex the text.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you. This has helped me reach a solution (updated the question).

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you. This has helped me reach a solution (updated the question).

Comment: @MarkTolonen This was part of a collection of zipped JSONs when you download your Instagram data

Comment: Did you read the JSON with UTF-8 encoding?  Reading the file with the wrong encoding would generate the strings you have.  The other possibility is it was written incorrectly to JSON in the first place.

Comment: I don't know PHP, but in Python I can show that it is mis-decoded.  Re-encode in the incorrect encoding and decode in the correct one: `'\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')` -> `'日本'`

Comment: @MarkTolonen Initially I believe it was read that way (though I'm not particularly good with PHP so I could be wrong). One main issue was that even when the string was manually added to the PHP code the result was the same (I'll add a PHP Sandbox link above so you can see the result of all attempts at once).

Comment: When you read the *byte* 0xE6 from a file as Latin-1, you get the Unicode codepoint  U+00E6 (`\u00e6`).  When you read the *bytes* 0xE6 0x97 0xA5 from a file as UTF-8, you get the Unicode code point U+65E5 (`\u65e5` -> `日`). So at some point in the process the file was read and incorrectly translated from bytes to code points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):

```
print('\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac'.encode('latin1').decode())
```

> ```
> 日本
> ```

Let's rewrite above code in `PHP` terms (utilizing the `json_decode` function):

```
<?php

$str_chin = "日本";
echo $str_chin . " => test: chinese to JSON => "
               . json_encode($str_chin) . PHP_EOL;

$str = '\u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac';
$str_moj = json_decode('"' . $str . '"', JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE ); 

echo $str . " => mojibake => "
          . $str_moj . PHP_EOL;

echo $str . " => solution => " 
          . mb_convert_encoding($str_moj, 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');

?>
```

**Output:**

```
73099438.php
```

> ```
> 日本 => test: chinese to JSON => "\u65e5\u672c"
> \u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac => mojibake => æ¥æ¬
> \u00e6\u0097\u00a5\u00e6\u009c\u00ac => solution => 日本
> ```

Comment: That's great, so I needed to do the mb_convert_encoding on top of the json_decode. Or as a single line: echo mb_convert_encoding(json_decode('"' . $str . '"', JSON_INVALID_UTF8_IGNORE ), 'iso-8859-1', 'utf-8');